# Fetch zoho timesheet data for custom range of date using zoho timesheet api in postman

Tags: postman, zoho

In postman to fetch custom_data from api i have passed the below url with params, portalid, projectid but is showing "Bad Request"

```
https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal/portalid/projects/projectid/logs/?users_list=all&view_type=custom_date&bill_status=all&approval_status=all&component_type=task&custom_date={start_date: 03-06-2023, end_date: 03-10-2023}
```

So i am asking how to use the custom date params in postman.

I want custom date range in postman